# error TS2352: Conversion of type 'Session | null' to type '{ x: string; y: string; }' may be a mistake

Tags: typescript

Initially I got these errors

```
server.ts:30:12 - error TS2339: Property 'shop' does not exist on type 'Session | null'.

30     const {shop, accessToken} = ctx.session;
              ~~~~

server.ts:30:18 - error TS2339: Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'Session | null'.

30     const {shop, accessToken} = ctx.session;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

After writing `const {shop, accessToken} = ctx.session as {shop: string, accessToken: string}` I am seeing the following:

```
server.ts:48:31 - error TS2352: Conversion of type 'Session | null' to type '{ shop: string; accessToken: string; }' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'Session' is missing the following properties from type '{ shop: string; accessToken: string; }': shop, accessToken

48   const {shop, accessToken} = ctx.session as {shop: string, accessToken: string};
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[4:52:59 AM] Found 4 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

I am new to Typescript but believe I have 2 options

1. Rewrite the line to `const {shop, accessToken} = ctx.session as unknown as {shop: string, accessToken: string}`
2. Write an interface for `Session` and assert ctx.session to it (`ctx.session as Session`), overwriting the previous type assignment (Session|null).

Is this correct? What is the better choice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "session" can be null, and null doesn't contain any property.

Try one of these:

```
const {shop, accessToken} = ctx.session!;
```

Or:

```
if (ctx.session === null) { return; } // Or throw, or next()
const {shop, accessToken} = ctx.session;
```